# Android ksoap 2 (2.6) web service with android 2.2 version ko and not with android 4.0.3

Tags: android, web-services, ksoap2

**My call of web service is ok with android 4.0.3** but **it is Ko with 2.2 version**. 
It's a SOAP web service JBOSS 4.2.2. 
use ksoap2-android-assembly-2.6.0

I have an exception:

unexpected type (position:END_DOCUMENT null@1:0 in java.io.InputStreamReader@44f36cb0)

the code:

```
private static final String METHOD_NAME_findBeneficiaireLight = "findBeneficiaireLight";
private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://service.android.interiale.fr/";
private static final String URL = "http://10.0.2.2:8090/mgpatInternet-mgpatInternetEJB/AdherentService";

public BeneficiaireLight getBeneficiaire(String user_id, String password, SharedPreferences settings)
        throws AuthentificationFailureException, WebConnectionException {
    BeneficiaireLight results = null;

    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE,
            METHOD_NAME_findBeneficiaireLight);
    request.addProperty("arg0", user_id);

    SoapSerializationEnvelope soapenvelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
            SoapEnvelope.VER11);

    soapenvelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    soapenvelope.addMapping(NAMESPACE,
            BeneficiaireLight.BeneficiaireLight_CLASS.getSimpleName(),
            BeneficiaireLight.BeneficiaireLight_CLASS);

    HttpTransportSE httptransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
     httptransport.debug = true;

    List<HeaderProperty> headers = new ArrayList<HeaderProperty>();
    headers.add(new HeaderProperty("Authorization", "Basic "
            + Base64.encodeToString(
                    (user_id.toLowerCase() + ":" + password).getBytes(),
                    Base64.DEFAULT)));

    try {
        httptransport.call(NAMESPACE + METHOD_NAME_findBeneficiaireLight,
                soapenvelope, headers);
        Object res = (Object)soapenvelope.getResponse();

        if (res instanceof SoapObject) {
            results = new BeneficiaireLight((SoapObject) res);


        }

    } catch (SocketException ex) {
        Log.e("Error : ", "Error on getBeneficiaire() " + ex.getMessage());
        throw new WebConnectionException("service " + NAMESPACE
                + METHOD_NAME_findBeneficiaireLight + " KO", ex);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Error : ", "Error on getBeneficiaire() " + e.getMessage());
        throw new AuthentificationFailureException();
    }
    return results;
```

Answer (score 1):

check your following code

```
Object res = (Object)soapenvelope.getResponse();

    if (res instanceof SoapObject) {
        results = new BeneficiaireLight((SoapObject) res);


    }
```

when there is error you are not getting SoapObject that time u will get SoapFault object u have to handle that

Comment: yes I handle that now. but there 's no probem with android 4.0.3.. it's with 2.2. what I must do to be compatible with 2.2?

Answer (score 0):

Might be a http transport or timing related issue. Try implementing a retry .. my call sometimes succeed at second hit.. and normally it should just work with both. My codebase works from 1.6 up.